# How to automatically add // on new line of comment in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, comments

In Visual Studio, I am trying to automatically add the comment marker `//` when I enter a new line in a comment similar to how visual studio adds a preceding `*` in a block comment. For bonus points, I would also like it to keep the indentation of the previous line, which it also does for block comments. Looking through the options and available extensions, I was not able to find a settings to do this, although it seems like it would be fairly straight forward since it would just have to look for `//` instead of `/*`.

I work in both C# and C++ so it would be preferable if this would work for both, and on my setup it doesn't appear that VS adds the asterisk in C++.

Comment: it works by default for `///` ... at least in vs2010

Comment: yes, it works for XML comments but not normal comments